# How can I pass non summary data through a group statement in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the many companies. Some of the companies have subjects and others do not. All companies have a Modified date and a modified by. Something like this:

```
CompanyID  Subjects Modified      Modified By
1          2        Jan 1, 2011   Jon
2          4        Jan 1, 2010   Dave
3          1        Jan 1, 2009   Alan
4          0        Jan 1, 2008   Tom
```

With a lot of help from people here I created a LINQ report that gave me the information I needed but it didn't show the Modified date and who modified the Company record

```
 var abc = from c in companies
           join s in subjects on "0000" + c.RowKey equals s.PartitionKey into outer
           from s in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new
           {
               Title = c.Title,
               Subject = ((s == null) ? 0 : 1)
               //, Modified = c.Modified,
               // ModifiedBy = c.ModifiedBy
           } into split
           group split by split.Title into g
           select new CompanySummary
           {
               Title = g.Key,
               Subjects = g.Sum(s => s.Subject)
               // ,Modified = g.Modified,
               // ModifiedBy = g.ModifiedBy
           };
```

I tried to add the code (commented out) to give the modified details for the companies. However it gave me an error saying:

```
Error   1   'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Modified' and no extension method 'Modified' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,AnonymousType#1>'
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong. My code is 95% working but I just can't figure out how to pass through the modified details to the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g` is a set of objects.
The set itself obviously has no properties, other than the common key.

You need to get the properties from a specific object inside each group, such as `g.Last()`.

Comment: Hello Slaks. Thanks and now I understand. If you don't mind can you tell me the syntax that I could use for this. I tried to add: Modified = g.Last(Modified),
                                      ModifiedBy = g.Last(ModifiedBy) but this did not work.

Comment: `ModifiedBy = g.Last().ModifiedBy`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick but now I get an error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'   In my Company I have this set to public DateTime? ModifiedBy { get; set; }